# Toggling a radio button (actually checkbox) with Applescript in System Settings (MacOS 13.4.1)

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility

How do I access the Checkbox in System Settings -> Accessibility -> Pointer Control -> Alternative Pointer options? This is failing to find it.. I've tried the anchor name. Is it because its not a checkbox? its not a radio button either even though it looks like one!

```
 tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    reveal anchor "AX_MOUSE_KEYS" of pane id "com.apple.Accessibility-Settings.extension"
end tell



delay 2



tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Settings"
        click checkbox named "Alternative Pointer Actions" of window named "Pointer Control"
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
tell application "System Settings"
    activate
    reveal anchor "AX_ALT_MOUSE_BUTTONS" of pane id "com.apple.Accessibility-Settings.extension"
end tell
delay .1
tell application "System Events" to tell application process "System Settings"
    click UI element 8 of group 2 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of group 2 of splitter group 1 of group 1 of window "Pointer Control"
end tell
delay .1
```

Comment: Amazing. But how did you figure out the number and all those group numbers? Does the accessibility checker provide this in some way?

Comment: accessibility checker does help, plus some try-and-error.